# Switching to Landscape is not switching to correct XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have an activity that loads a container xml and loads a ListFragment into it. The ListFragment xml has a layout and a layout-land version.  When starting the app, it loads correctly for both the layout and the layout-land.  However, switching the orientation of the device does not properly load the new layout.  Interestingly, the xml for the list item correctly switches.

The xml for the two versions is very similar, with the difference being that the firstHeader width being 200dp on the layout-land version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp" >

    <!-- List Header -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateHeader"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Date" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstHeader"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="First" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/secondHeader"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Second" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/thirdHeader"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Third" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

There is only one FrameLayout that is shared by both:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</FrameLayout>
```

Any ideas as to what could be going on here?

EDIT: I was using:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|keyboard|locale
```

and I think that this is the issue.  I removed this and am running into some other issues, but that will be addressed elsewhere.

Comment: did you try to move xml from `layout` to `layout-port`?

Comment: That was a worthwhile idea, but it didn't change the behavior.  Thanks, though.